# Java library to create graphs

Tags: java, swing, graphic

What is best and easy to use library for Java graphs? I am working with Swing application and need to integrate a graph for that project

Comment: What do you mean by 'Java graphs' ?

Comment: I'd recommend the relatively new library, XChart to anyone who is visiting this post closer to 2015

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One commonly used charting API is [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).

Comment: can you give me sample code for how to use that Library. i Try to find. But i fail. Only i get it the API. But i can't find any sample code.

Comment: See also the `JFreeChart` [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Comment: Are there also a non sourceForge repository? (==no malware)

Answer (score 14):

### Options

- If graphs you mean like clusters nodes and links visualization have a look at [graphviz gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)
- To generate charts see [jfreechart demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/)  Download [jfreechart jfreechart-1.0.13](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/1.%20JFreeChart/1.0.13/jfreechart-1.0.13.zip/download)
- Use [java advanced imaging - jai](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/)  see  [histogram demo source](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/javaai/jai/HistogramDemo.java)

### Steps to create a chart using jfreechart

Create Dataset and pass array of data

```
HistogramDataset dataset = new HistogramDataset();
dataset.addSeries("series label",arrayOfValues,noOfBins);
```

Create a chart object

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.
createHistogram( "plotTitle", "xaxis label", "yaxis label", 
                dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
```

If swing application use `ChartPanel` to render chart

```
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart)
chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension JavaDoc(500, 270));
chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
```

If need to write chart to a file/stream use `ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(...)`

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("histogram.PNG"), chart, width, height);
```

Comment: No,, i just want to create a histogram for a given image.

Comment: oh i see , I have updated the answer to reflect what you might need to use

Comment: I will check that. thank you for your kindly response.

Comment: How can i use that library to create a histogram (or bar char)

Comment: the sample code that given is too hard to under stand. because i am new to Java. So can you please help me to create a chart. I have the data in 2D array and a JPanel to display chart.

Comment: DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset(); is not working... ask for the class even i linked the JAR file and import the import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

Comment: how can i link the JAR file in to my net-beans project. I already add the JAR file in to the library. But when compiling it says that 'HistogramDataset' class can't find???

Comment: make sure that you have both jfreechart-1.0.13.jar and jcommons-1.0.13.jar on the build path

Comment: addSeries(Comparable key, double[] values, int bins) what is the parameter for 'key' it is not accepting the String

Answer (score 5):

I answered in this thread, could be helpful [Java graph library for dynamic visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation/6163369#6163369)