# Draw a dynamic graph?

Tags: dynamic, graph

I have a program that I wrote in Java takes in a set of actions and prints out a graph after every action. Another way to look at it is that the program prints out the output of the graph at every time-step. I need to display this dynamic graph visually and I have been considering some softwares like gephi. I would like to know that what would be the best way to go about doing it and it seems like gephi does not support this feature. Should i build a java applet and if so does java provide any libraries.

I want to display the entire graph with nodes and edges between them. The edges will display the actions between the nodes and each action will result in some values being changed in the nodes. The nodes will display the value being changed and edges will be marked with the action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jfreechart supports dynamic graphs. There is a lot of tutorials on the web as well. I think this thread might be helpful

[Using JFreeChart to display recent changes in a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863)

Comment: no i am not looking to display timeline and charts. I want to display the entire graph with nodes and edges between them. The edges will display the actions between the nodes and each action will result in some values being changed in the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

check out [Gephi](https://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Import_Dynamic_Data), [Sonia](http://www.stanford.edu/group/sonia/), or the [ndtv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ndtv/) and networkDynamic libraries in R (if you don't mind writing out to files and post processing).  Also, this thread has other suggestions: [Java graph library for dynamic visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation)