# Use Neo4j Browser Visualisation as JS

Tags: neo4j, cypher, visualization

I want to display my data from my **Neo4j DB** in a seperate Website.
Therefore I am learning about **d3.js**.

In fact I would like to use the visualization, which is used in the **Neo4j Browser**, just a little modified.

Is there a way to do this. If i am using another d3.js visualization i have to do a lot of modifications .

Im actually pretty new to it. It would be very nice if someone would help me out.

Thanks and Greetings
Schakron

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772701/neo4j-visualisation-manipulate-the-graph , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922705/how-to-visualise-neo4j-graph-database-created-from-an-embedded-neo4j-java-applic , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964056/graph-visualization-frameworks (and many others...)

Answer (score 1):

See: http://github.jexp.de/cy2neo there is a branch that uses a derivation of the browser viz