# Neo4J - How best to get a minimal ASCII-art representation of graph?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the Neo4J Java Traversal API and have a number of tests around my code.

Debugging would be a lot easier if I could log an ASCII-art representation of the graph in a failing test.

Obviously "logging" a Neo4J graph is unwieldy in production code, but is practical in tests as the graphs only comprise a handful of nodes and relationships.

How best to get an ASCII art representation of a Neo4J graph, please?

Comment: How about just graphviz ? http://neo4j.com/blog/graph-this-rendering-your-graph-with-graphviz/

Comment: Or just export it to cypher :) which is an ascii-art-graph representation, I think that's what graphawares testing framework does: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest

Comment: Another way to export to Cypher is to use the neo4j-shell's `dump` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the various visualisation libraries, but it seems few, if any, work well with a simple embedded `ImpermanentDatabase`. I don't want to have to rely on an external tool for this.

I've settled on running adhoc Cypher queries and dumping the result to console:

```scala
println(new ExecutionEngine(db).execute(
  "match (p:USER)-[r]-(c:USER) return p.screenname, r, c.screenname"
).dumpToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems like that would be painful.  What about using a library that generates visual graphs to an image file and generating/opening that file on failure?  This post seems to have some good libraries for generating graph visualizations in java:

[Java graph library for dynamic visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation)

Comment: Agreed it would be painful, but images are not much of a solution; they might work in this narrow case maybe, but they can't be grepped of course.

Comment: I don't know about ASCII art but the closest thing I can think of is maybe something like RDF Turtle.  It's a simple text compact format for expressing a graph (albeit RDF, would need adaptation for neo4j).  It would be hard to figure out how much to put on a line.  If the graph was a tree root X with 3 children, should it be written as (X)->(A), (X)->(B), (X)->(C) or what?