# Visualizing graph database from java

Tags: twitter, neo4j, twitter4j

I'm making a java application to retrieve data from twitter and then store the data in a graph database Neo4j. I wonder if I can visualize the social graph via my application from java?! I mean , can I visualize the graph using CYPHER queries from java in order to see the different nodes and relationships?! 
Thanks

Comment: Is it a web or a desktop application?

Comment: A desktop application

Comment: Maybe these answers can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation

Comment: Yeah , actually I have seen the answers in here, and I know I can work with prefuse,  but I wonder if I can directly visualise the graph via the Neo4j interface or something by sending queries from java via URL ?! Is that even possible !

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing that, see

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/

for a concrete twitter example using vivagraph.js

http://neo4j.com/blog/oscon-twitter-graph/

Comment: For a desktop application you can look into JUNG or Prefuse.