# how to plot a graph from collections contents in java

Tags: java, graph, graph-visualization

i have parsed a raw xml file and fetched many vertices and the edges that i would need, but i cant able to actually plot it... i.e, suppose i have the hashmap containing the folowing key-->value pair...
the HashMap is of following type pair "String,ArrayList of String"

A--------->[B, C]

B--------->[H, J]

Y--------->[Z]

for the above contents, i want a graph similar to this:
[image]
i can't able to find the solution for this anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-visualization+java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the dot language, it is a simple text format.

But there is even a pure Java lib for it:
https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java

```
import static guru.nidi.graphviz.model.Factory.*
Graph g = graph("example1").directed().with(node("a").link(node("b")));
Graphviz.fromGraph(g).width(200).render(Format.PNG).toFile(new File("example/ex1.png"));
```

Adapt this example ... and it should work.

There are other solutions see:

[Java graph library for dynamic visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162618/java-graph-library-for-dynamic-visualisation)

In the worst case just generate dot text and render outside of java using graphviz.

Comment: How exactly? i mean i tried your method, but its throwing NoSuchElementException..      Graph g = null;  
    for(String ke : domParser.hashMap.keySet()) {  
     Iterator<String> it =  
 domParser.hashMap.get(ke).iterator();  
     while(it.hasNext()) {  
      graph.addEdge(ke, it.next().toString());  
      g =  
 graph("ex").directed().with(node(ke).link(node(it.next().toString())));  
     }  
    }  
      
    try {  
   
 Graphviz.fromGraph(g).width(200).render(Format.PNG).toFile(new File("example/ex1.png"));  
 } catch (IOException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
 }

Comment: I dont why the formatting doesnt work..sorry for that

Comment: See the docs on the graphviz-java site, if it does not work, try other links.