# Tree/dendrogram with elbow connectors in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dendrogram

I'm very new to d3.js (and SVG in general), and I want to do something simple: a tree/dendrogram with angled connectors.

I have cannibalised the d3 example from here:http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html 
and I want to make it more like the protovis examples here:

- http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/indent.html
- http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/dendrogram.html

I have made a start here: http://jsbin.com/ugacud/2/edit#javascript,html and I think it's the following snippet that's wrong:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

However there's no obvious replacement, I could use `d3.svg.line`, but I don't know how to integrate it properly, and ideally I'd like an elbow connector....although I am wondering if I am using the wrong library for this, as a lot of the d3 examples I've seen are using the gravitational force to do graphs of objects instead of trees.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Replace the `diagonal` function with a custom path generator, using SVG's "H" and "V" [path commands](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

```
function elbow(d, i) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
      + "V" + d.target.x + "H" + d.target.y;
}
```

Note that the source and target's coordinates (*x* and *y*) are swapped. This example displays the layout with a horizontal orientation, however the layout always uses the same coordinate system: *x* is the breadth of the tree, and *y* is the depth of the tree. So, if you want to display the tree with the leaf (bottommost) nodes on the right edge, then you need to swap *x* and *y*. That's what the diagonal's projection function does, but in the above elbow implementation I just hard-coded the behavior rather than using a [configurable function](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/).

As in:

```
svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(cluster.links(nodes))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", elbow);
```

And a working example:

- http://bl.ocks.org/d/2429963/

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was hoping you'd see this question! I'll give this a go and report back later....Are there any good SVG tutorial sites that you'd recommend reading?....bearing in mind, I know nothing at all?

Comment: hey @mbostock , i am using your elbow code now , but when combined with toggling (expand , collaspe) it no longer works (Diagonal works fine). Can you explain how i can get it to work?