# Rotate D3 tree from vertical to horizontal

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am new in D3 and developing a family tree using d3v4(for some constraints not using latest version of d3. Though I am using latest d3 cdn but my requirement is d3v4). The family tree is vertical i.e., parent is in top and children are in bottom. But I want to turn the tree and want to make it horizontal i.e., parent is in left and children are in right.
Kindly find my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 600)
                        .attr("height", 600)
                        .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");
            
            var data = [
                {
                    "child": {
                        "type": "from",
                        "name": "John",
                        "factor": 5
                    },
                    "parent": ""
                },
                {
                    "child": {
                        "type": "cc",
                        "name": "Kevin",
                        "factor": 4
                    },
                    "parent": {
                        "type": "from",
                        "name": "John",
                        "factor": 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "child": {
                        "type": "bcc",
                        "name": "Mary",
                        "factor": 6
                    },
                    "parent": {
                        "type": "from",
                        "name": "John",
                        "factor": 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "child": {
                        "type": "cc",
                        "name": "Mars",
                        "factor": 5
                    },
                    "parent": {
                        "type": "from",
                        "name": "John",
                        "factor": 5
                    }
                }
            ]
            
            
            
            
            var datastructure = d3.stratify()
                                    .id(function(d) { return d.child.name; })
                                    .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent.name; })
                                    (data);
            
            var treeStructure = d3.tree().size([500, 300]);
            var information = treeStructure(datastructure);
//            console.log(information.descendants());
//            console.log(information.links());
            
            var circles = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
                            .data(information.descendants());
            
            var markerBoxWidth = 20;
            var markerBoxHeight = 20;
            var refX = markerBoxWidth / 2;
            var refY = markerBoxHeight / 2;
            var markerWidth = markerBoxWidth / 2;
            var markerHeight = markerBoxHeight / 2;
            var arrowPoints = [[0, 0], [0, 20], [20, 10]];
            
            svg
                .append('defs')
                .append('marker')
                .attr('id', 'arrow')
                .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, markerBoxWidth, markerBoxHeight])
                .attr('refX', refX)
                .attr('refY', refY)
                .attr('markerWidth', markerBoxWidth)
                .attr('markerHeight', markerBoxHeight)
                .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
                .append('path')
                .attr('d', d3.line()(arrowPoints))
                .attr('fill', 'red');
            
            circles.enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { 
                    //    console.log(d)
                        return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
                    .attr("r", function(d) {
                        //console.log()
                    return d.data.child.factor * 3;
            })
                    .attr("fill", function(d) {
                
                    if (d.data.child.type === 'from') {
                        return "blue";
                    } else if (d.data.child.type === 'cc') {
                        return "yellow";
                    } else if (d.data.child.type === 'bcc') {
                        return "red";
                    }
            });
            
            var connections = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
                                .data(information.links());
            
            connections.enter().append("path")
                        .attr("d", function(d) {
                                console.log(d);
                                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + (d.source.y + (d.source.data.child.factor * 3)) 
                                    + " C " +
                                d.source.x + "," + (d.source.y + d.target.y)/2 + " " + 
                                d.target.x + "," + (d.source.y + d.target.y)/2 + " " +
                                d.target.x + "," + (d.target.y - (d.target.data.child.factor * 3));
            }).attr("fill", "none").attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)')
    .attr('fill', 'none');
            
            var names = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
                            .data(information.descendants());
                            
                            const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, 8])
                 .range([0, 1000]);
            
            names.enter().append("text")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.data.child.name; })
                        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could swap y and x values throughout the code, this is the typical approach taken, [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249720/7106086)